# VB Copy specific files by Extensions

Tags: windows, vb6, text-files

Can anybody give me any pointers on the below script I'm trying to create please,  basically I'm trying search for certain folders under a parent but the general child structure is roughly the same, if exists then copy certain extensions, but not all extensions exist in all the child folders

When I run the Script I'm not getting any files copied into the "harvest" folder or any child Folders created under the Harvest folder, both Folders and files all exist when Testing this script

Any Help Much appreciated

```
advancedPath = InputBox("Type the Application Sharepoint")
advancedDBPath = InputBox("Type the Database Folder")
harvestFolder = InputBox("Type the Harvest Folder")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

' Check if Harvest folder exist if not create
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(harvestFolder) Then
objFSO.CreateFolder(harvestFolder)
End If

'Extensions to copy
extStr = Array("*.ini", "*.pf","*.bat","*.admin","*.st","*.ver","*.propath")

If objFSO.FolderExists(advancedPath & "oalive80") Then
' Check if Oalive80 exist   
If objFSO.FolderExists(advancedPath & "oalive80") = TRUE Then
 objFSO.CreateFolder(harvestFolder & "oalive80")
 objFSO.CopyFile advancedPath & "oalive80" & "\"  & extStr, harvestFolder & "oalive80", false
 objFSO.CopyFile advancedPath & "oalive80\oahfb10" & "\"  & extStr, harvestFolder & "oalive80", false
End If

' Check if Oatest80 exist   
If objFSO.FolderExists(advancedPath & "oatest80") = TRUE Then
 objFSO.CreateFolder(harvestFolder & "oatest80")
 objFSO.CopyFile advancedPath & "oatest80" & "\"  & extStr, harvestFolder & "oatest80", false
End If

' Check if oplive exist     
If objFSO.FolderExists(advancedPath & "oplive") = TRUE Then
 objFSO.CreateFolder(harvestFolder " "oplive")
 objFSO.CopyFile advancedPath & "oplive\gclib\pf" & "\" & extStr, harvestFolder & "oplive" false
End If

' Check if Live DB folder exist     
If objFSO.FolderExists(advancedDBPath & "oalive80") = TRUE Then
 objFSO.CreateFolder(harvestFolder & "LiveDB")
 objFSO.CopyFile advancedDBPath & "oalive80\oa_data" & "\" & extStr, harvestFolder & "LiveDB", false
End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a loop for the array, as shown below, for each of your copy code

```
  For iCt = 0 To UBound(extStr)
    strExtn = extStr(iCt)
    objFSO.CopyFile advancedPath & "oalive80" & "\"  & strExtn , harvestFolder & "oalive80", false
  Next
```

Maybe use a function like shown below for your code:

```
Private Sub BulkCopyFile(ByVal objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, ByVal strSourceFolder As String, ByVal strDestinationFolder As String)
  extStr = Array("*.ini", "*.pf","*.bat","*.admin","*.st","*.ver","*.propath")
  For iCt = 0 To UBound(extStr)
    strExtn = extStr(iCt)
    objFSO.CopyFile strSourceFolder & strExtn, strDestinationFolder, False
  Next
End Sub
```

Example usage for your code

```
' Check if Oalive80 exist
If objFSO.FolderExists(advancedPath & "oalive80") = True Then
  objFSO.CreateFolder (harvestFolder & "oalive80")
  Call BulkCopyFile(objFSO, advancedPath & "oalive80" & "\", harvestFolder & "oalive80")
  Call BulkCopyFile(objFSO, advancedPath & "oalive80\oahfb10" & "\", harvestFolder & "oalive80")
End If
```

Comment: cheers for the detailed response and code, I have tried that code, the line Private Sub BulkCopyFile(ByVal objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject, ByVal strSourceFolder As String, ByVal strDestinationFolder As String" I then get the error ......"User define type not defined"

Comment: Im using Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0